# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{an+b}$ ever converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, analysis

For which complex numbers $a,b$, if any, does the sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{an+b}$ converge?

---

What I've worked out: if $a$ and $b$ are non-zero positive numbers, then the series diverges. To see this, take $M$ large enough so that $Mn\geq |an+b|$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ ($M>|a|+|b|$ suffices) and observe that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{Mn}\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{an+b}$$

where the first sum diverges.

Comment: You are correct.  It always diverges. [In fact, there could even be a problem writing the series if $an+b=0$ for some $n$.  In that case one of the terms does not exist, so it is senseless to ask whether the series converges or diverges.]

Comment: The case of $b$ being zero or negative is also proved in your case, since you just make $M$ larger than $b$, and the case of $a$ being negative is also similar, so you have finished the job already.

Comment: For the comlpex case your argument doesn't work. It only proves tha the series is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: @GEdgar For the comlpex case OP's argument doesn't work. It only proves that the series is not absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 2):

Hints: $\frac  1 {an+b}=\frac {\overline a n +\overline b} { |an+b|^{2}}$. If $a \neq 0$  then $|an+b| \leq |a| n+|b|$ shows divergence  of $\frac {n } { |an+b|^{2}}$(by divergence of  $\sum \frac  1 n$) and the series $\sum \frac {{\overline b}} {|an+b|^{2}}$ is convergent so the given series is divergent.

If $a =0, b \neq 0$  then the general term does not tend to $0$ so we  get divergence. If $a=b=0$ the series is not defined.

Conclusion: The given series is never convergent.

Comment: This feels a bit overcomplicated to me. If $a=0$ the divergence is obvious since you're summing a constant.

Comment: @SuzuHirose That is what I am saying The non-trivial case is when $a\neq 0$.

Comment: My comment is referring to the initial version of your answer, https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4470015/1.

Comment: @SuzuHirose In the complex case Op's argument only proves that the series is not absolutely convergent. To prove that it is not convergent you have to do some work I don't think my argument can be simplified. .

Answer (score 2):

The series is divergent for $a=0$ as the terms are constantly equal ${1\over b}.$ For $a\neq 0$ the series $\sum {1\over an}$ is divergent. Moreover
$${1\over an+b}={1\over an}+{b\over an(an+
b)}$$ The series with terms ${b\over an(an+b)}$ is absolutely convergent. Therefore the original series is not convergent.